# Can 2 private EndPoint talk to each other on Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-virtual-network

I have a Vnet and 2 private endpoints are connected to it. I was wondering if these two private endpoint could talk to each other and if they can is it on the Vnet or on the public internet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, yes--there is nothing stopping two services with private endpoints enabled from communicating, unless you implement a service firewall which requires requests to use the private endpoint, in which case, see below.

Consider that private endpoints are specific to inbound traffic--allowing you to resolve a PaaS service which would typically use a public IP to a private IP on your network.

With this in mind, and assuming you are only allowing traffic from your private endpoint, if resource A has a private endpoint and resource B attempts to communicate with A, B will need to be able to resolve the private IP address for A. If resource B is configured to resolve DNS requests at the DNS service where you have published your private endpoint DNS record for resource A (such as Azure DNS and with a Private DNS zone, or a custom DNS server), AND resource B is connected to your VNET, then resource B would resolve resource A's name to its private IP and the traffic would traverse the VNET.

Whether resource B also has a private endpoint configured does not change the flow from B to A.

Of course, this depends on the type of resources involved. You'd need support both for resolving the destination service name to your private endpoint IP and the ability to reach that IP.